# Split string is not matching

Tags: java

Here is the code I am using for the output in the end

```
public static String processMessage(String input)
{
    String[] token = input.split(" ");
    if (token[0] == "add")
        return "yeah its a match";
    else
        return "not a match";
}
```

Here is the image of my test

[image]

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (token[0] == "add")`

A String is an object, not a primitive data type. For that reason you should be using the object comparison method `.equals()`

e.g. `if token[0].equals("add")`

Also, if this is user input then consider `.equalsIgnoreCase()`

Comment: That works, sorry if it's a duplicate question.  Will check-mark this post when I can (9 minutes)